# SAPUI5 How to get object from context by value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sapui5

I'm building a SAPUI5 application in JS view i have a JSON model as follows

```
{
    "Categories": [
        {
            "name":"L1 Category One",
            "icon":"sap-icon://home",
            "description":"Sample Description",
            "sub-categories":{[
                                  {
                                       "name":"L2 Category One",
                                       "icon":"sap-icon://action",
                                       "description":"Sample Description",
                                  }
                            ]}
        }
        {
            "name":"L1 Category Two",
            "icon":"sap-icon://action",
            "description":"Sample Description"
        }
        {
            "name":"L1 Category Three",
            "icon":"sap-icon://doctor",
            "description":"Sample Description"
        }
        {
            "name":"L1 Category Four",
            "icon":"sap-icon://cart",
            "description":"Sample Description"
        }
                 ]
}
```

I'm building a tile like category navigation using this model as follows

```
        var oSampleLayout = new sap.ui.layout.HorizontalLayout("cats-layout");

        oSampleLayout.setModel(oModel);

        var ooCategoryIcon = new sap.ui.core.Icon();

        ooCategoryIcon.setSrc("{icon}");

        ooCategoryIcon.addStyleClass("category-icon");

        var ooCategoryName = new sap.ui.commons.TextView();

        ooCategoryName.setText("{name}");

        var oOtherTemplate = new sap.ui.commons.layout.VerticalLayout("",{content:[ooCategoryIcon,ooCategoryName]});

        oOtherTemplate.addStyleClass("cat");

        oOtherTemplate.attachBrowserEvent('click',soidPress);

        oSampleLayout.bindAggregation("content",{path:"/Categories",template:oOtherTemplate});

        oSampleLayout.placeAt('other-content');
```

on click I'm getting the binding context and calling a method to render the subcategories where I'm passing the context to the render method but I'm stuck in getting the subcategories rendered How can i do that? Any Ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've set the context.oModel as the model to the sub categories and have bound the element using the context path as

```
oxLayout.bindElement(oContext.sPath);
```

this allowed me to bind the particular element from the contexts path and use the aggregation again forming the sub-categories.